# Restructure array based on a particular key together- javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array like so:

```
 const data = [
    {category: {id: 1, name: 'beverage'}, title: 'Tea'},
    {category: {id: 1, name: 'beverage'}, title: 'Coffee'},
    {category: {id: 2, name: 'snacks'}, title: 'French fries'},
  ];
```

I want the result like so:

```
const transformed = [
  {
    category: "beverage",
    data: [{title:'coffee'},{title:'tea'}, ...]
  },
  {
    category: "snacks",
    data: [{title:'french fries'},...]
  },
..
]
```

What i did was:

```
 let transformed = data?.map(function (obj) {
    var result = {
      category: obj.category.title,
      data: [],
    };
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key === 'category') {
        result.values.push(obj);
      }
    }

    return result;
  });
```

But with this approach i am getting duplicate category names for every object in the array.

Comment: I'm confused on the expected result's second value being title where first is category... explanation on that or just something you missed? And if it's not an error, what differs from the two?

Comment: with ur code i get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`

Comment: The new array should contain objects based on category names. For example the first object should contain the category name 'beverage' and then an array of beverage items in the list. It was mistakenly quoted as title instead of category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all grouping operations the key is to use `reduce` to build up a new object.

```js
const data = [
    {category: {id: 1, name: 'beverage'}, title: 'Tea'},
    {category: {id: 1, name: 'beverage'}, title: 'Coffee'},
    {category: {id: 2, name: 'snacks'}, title: 'French fries'},
  ];
  
const result = Object.values(data.reduce( (a,i) => {
    a[i.category.id] = a[i.category.id] || {category:i.category.name, data:[]};
    a[i.category.id].data.push({title:i.title});
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Clean! :) :thumbsup:

Answer (score 3):

You could group by `name` of `category` and use an object for getting groupd values.

```js
const 
    data = [{ category: { id: 1, name: 'beverage' }, title: 'Tea' }, { category: { id: 1, name: 'beverage' }, title: 'Coffee' }, { category: { id: 2, name: 'snacks' }, title: 'French fries' }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { category: { name: category }, title  }) => {
        (r[category] ??= { category, data: [] }).data.push({ title });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice and clean! Pretty code.

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the pattern used to solve this problem? When we group objects by property and return the answer as Object.values(...)

Comment: it has no real name, but it's grouping with a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
const data = [
    {category: {id: 1, name: 'beverage'}, title: 'Tea'},
    {category: {id: 1, name: 'beverage'}, title: 'Coffee'},
    {category: {id: 2, name: 'snacks'}, title: 'French fries'},
  ];

const transform = (data) => {
  const grouped = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const { category: { id, name }, title } = obj;
    acc[id] = (acc[id]) 
      ? { 
          ...acc[id], 
          data: [...acc[id].data, { title }], 
        }
      : { category: name, data: [{ title }] };

    return acc; 
  }, {});
  
  return Object.values(grouped);
};

console.dir(transform(data), {depth: null});
// [
//   { category: 'beverage', data: [{ title: 'Tea' }, { title: 'Coffee' }] },
//   { category: 'snacks', data: [{ title: 'French fries' }]}
// ]
```